# Emberjs: How to tell if a record wasn't found?

Tags: ember.js, local-storage, ember-data

I've got an app where I need to query for a related record that may or may not exist. If it exists, I need to update the value. If not, I need to create it.

How can I use `this.store.find` to handle the case where the model doesn't exist?

E.g. my code is:

```
// todo: now save this answer into the completed survey
self.store.find('answer', {completed_survey: completedSurvey,
                           question: question}).then(function(answer) {
  answer.set('value', formAnswerText);
  answer.save();
});        // what if there was no object found though?
```

Comment: You gotta handle 404 status: https://gist.github.com/pixelhandler/8856330

Comment: I'm using the localstorage adapater, so there is no 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you have a error handler

```
.then(function(model){},function(error){})
```

or you just check if its null

```
if(model){
//found
}else{
//notfound
}
```